# What does "cache" parameter mean for git fsck?

Tags: git

From the documentation, its unclear even whether it outputs more or less of Unreachable items .

```
git fsck --unreachable --cache
```

Comment: "Consider any object recorded in the index also as a head node for an unreachability trace." Is the question, "what does that mean"?

Comment: @matt , yes . in git, "objects" are used to call `.git\objects\<<..>>\<<_>>` (and other) items . the "recorded" can mean that some "objects" are cached in Index, and that they are mentioned there . and on top of this, "for an unreachability trace" can mean using them to find ways of Reaching, and checking whether they are Reachable . this doc's sentence is more flawed than useful, so the question is does anyone know what it really means ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Cache" is basically another synonym for the index or the staging area.

From `git help fsck`:

```
 --cache
           Consider any object recorded in the index also as a head node for
           an unreachability trace.
```

Cf. `git diff --cached`, which shows the diff between the current commit and the staged changes, rather than the current commit and the current working directory.

Comment: i know its related to index, see my comment to @ matt 's comment .

Comment: Do you understand what the index actually is?

Comment: its a git representation of Working Tree 's state, maybe includes Staged changes . as far i know .

Comment: Right: it's basically a virtual branch, and objects can be reachable from the index just like they are reachable from any other branch. By default, `fsck` does not consider something reachable *only* from the index as being reachable.

Comment: so `--cache` does make more Objects a Reachable ones (less ones output with `--unreachable`) ? exactly what i was worrying about .

Comment: I'd call the index more of a "virtual commit" than "virtual branch", but it amounts to the same thing.

Comment: @torek Fair point. The wording "head node" made me think of a branch head, but you're right, as the index is basically the thing that will become the next commit.